# How do I correctly memoize this recurrence relation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am solving a problem:

> Given a list of integers `nums`, write a function that returns the largest sum of non-adjacent numbers. Numbers can be `0` or negative.  For `nums = [5, 1, 1, 5]`, output should be `10`.

The dynamic programming logic that I have implemented is as below:

```cpp
vector<pair<int,int>> dp;

int helper(vector<int>& nums, int i, bool include) {
    if(i>=nums.size()) return 0;
    pair<int,int> p=dp[i];
    if(p.first!=INT_MIN) return p.second;
    
    int maxval=0;
    if(include) maxval=nums[i]+helper(nums,i+1,false);
    maxval=max(maxval,helper(nums,i+1,true));

    dp[i]=make_pair(include,maxval);
    return maxval;
}

int solve(vector<int>& nums) {
    dp.clear();
    dp.resize(nums.size(),make_pair(INT_MIN,INT_MIN));

    // For all -ve numbers in input, just return `0`, as required.
    int ans=max({helper(nums,0,true),helper(nums,0,false),0});

    //for(auto& p: dp) {
    //    cout<<p.first<<" "<<p.second<<"\n";
    //}

    return ans;
}
```

I get right answers when I don't do any memoization (so I think my recurrence relation is correct); but on memoizing it as above, I get wrong answers.

**Logic that I am using for memoization**: For the `i`th value, store a `pair<int,int>` in `dp[i]`, where the first value of pair represents the boolean value `include` while the second value of pair represents the result `maxvalue` calculated for current value of `i` and `include`.  Note that I use an `int` for a `bool`, since I need three values: `true`, `false` and "not yet calculated".

What am I missing in my memoization step?  Any better way in which I could memoize it?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong how? It's a little hard to follow the logic of your code just by scanning it. Have you tried picking a small input that you know doesn't work and stepping through in the debugger to see where things first diverge from your expectations?

Comment: For instance, at a glance, I'm not sure what exactly `dp` is supposed to be representing. What does the first integer of the pair mean? The second? Is `make_pair(include, maxval)` where `include` is a `bool` really meaningful?

Comment: To memoize a recursive DP solution, you need two steps: (1) Initially, set all values in the dp-table to a value that represents "haven't calculated this state yet". For instance, here, you could initialize dp with pairs {-1, -1}. (2) In your DP, at the very top, place the following check: If whatever entry you're currently wanting to calculate has ALREADY been calculated (i.e. the corresponding DP entry is NOT {-1, -1}), then just return the already-calculated value. This prevents re-computation of DP states.

Comment: looks like the problem is that you're just memozing based on `i` and not on `include` -- but the answer (result of helper) is different depending on whether `include` is true or false.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, could you please elaborate "memoizing based on `i` and not on `include`"?  I think I am memoizing on _both_, since I set the `i`th entry in the vector `dp` with the first value of the `pair` as `include` and the second value as maxval (result).

Comment: @Telescope, yes, I agree.  And IMO that is exactly what I am doing (using INT_MIN instead of `-1` though).

Comment: @NathanPierson, the first integer of the pair represents `include` (a `bool`), while the second presents the answer (`maxval`).  This pair is set for the `i`th entry in the vector `dp`.  Since `bool` has only two states `true` and `false`, I had to use  a third state to represent "not yet calculated", so I had to use an integer.  Do you have recommendations as to how I could memoize it differently?  What data structure could I use?  I used `unordered_map<string, int>` but that still resulted in TLE.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink it. Memoizing a function `f(P) { ... return Expr; }` where P is a tuple of parameters is always the same. Add an outer (not local to the recursive function) map M from tuples P to return values. Then rewrite f as

```
f(P) {
  if M contains key P, return M[P];
  ...
  t = Expr;
  M[P] = t;
  return t;
}
```

It looks like in your function, `nums` never changes.  So you can get away with omitting it from P.  If the remaining parameters are an `int` and a `bool`, and the function returns `int`, then key tuples have type `<int, bool>`, and the map returns `int`. That is `map<tuple<int, bool>, int>`.

*If* the map key ends up being a natural number, and the possible range is small, then you can replace the memo map with an array initialized with some value that means "no value." Then the "contains key" test becomes a check whether M[P] is something different from "no value." In practical problems, this doesn't often happen.

I'll let you work out the rest, since it seems you're learning. A note is that in a proper implementation you wouldn't make the map a global variable. You'd wrap the recursive method in a class and make `nums` and the memo cache both fields so they don't need to be passed as parameters.

Comment: With regard to your final paragraph, I wouldn't write a class for each function, I'd write one `memoise` template.

Comment: The issue with the map approach is that it keeps the elements in a sorted fashion (thus increasing the TC by a factor of `logN`).  This is the reason I consider different approaches to memoization (and probably overthink).

Answer (score 0):

```
int solve(const vector<int>& nums) {
    int N = nums.size();

    vector<int> dp(N, INT_MIN);
    function<int(int)> iter = [&](int i) {
        if(i>=N) { return 0; }
        if(dp[i] != INT_MIN) { return dp[i]; }
        return dp[i] = max(nums[i]+iter(i+2), iter(i+1));
    };
    
    return iter(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan through the array, recording the three largest numbers and their positions. If the larger two are not adjacent, then their sum is the answer. If the larger two are adjacent then either (#1 + #3) or (#2 + #3) will be the answer, depending on which is larger.

Comment: I am afraid this won't work: why do we consider just _3_ largest numbers? For e.g., if the input is `[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]`, why shouldn't we add alternate `1`s to our result?  If I understand you correctly, your answer would be `8`, while the correct answer should be `10`.

Comment: @J.  Doe How do you get 10 from `[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]`? The largest non-adjacent pair is 3 + 5 = 8. The 4 and 5 are adjacent so are not allowed.